# How to customize your VM on azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to Azure and cloud eco system. I just created a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - with Containers . This created a new VM ( windows 2016 server with docker containers). Now i need to install Visual Studio Express on this VM. What is the right way to install free version of Visual studio ?

In general when you need to install any software of Azure Cloud, what is the right approach ?

Comment: There is little difference between cloud VM and on-premises server. All you have to do is to access to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ from your VM and download it.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just install the free version of Visual Studio as what you do in your local machine as usual: download the package and then install it. You can almost do everything you want in your Azure VM.